# error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wanna run an app from android studio, but i give these errors
How can i solve it?
(i just installed androidStudio)[photo errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK0wU.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please, try to add codes as ```snippets``` instead of screenshots. What version of libraries are you using? AndroidX or the support libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your build.gradle file:

```
   implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1"
```